# wpf hide an element based on children count of another element in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

Using purely **XAML**, I want to hide an element, say a `textblock` or an `image` if a `list` or a `stackpanel` has elements.

For example, see the following code

```
<Label x:Name="LabelTobeHidden" 
       Content="No one has joined" 
       Visibility="Visible"
       />
<StackPanel x:Name="Players" Orientation="Vertical"/>
```

I can do this is cs, but I want to know of a way to do this solely in XAML to try my best to ensure that cs only has the application logic.

**Edit**:

I am adding elements to the stackpanel programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `DataTrigger` in a `Style` for that.

This is our `StackPanel` to watch for:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelToWatch" Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And here is the `Label` to hide:

```
<Label Content="text">
  <Label.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Children.Count, ElementName=StackPanelToWatch}" Value="0">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Comment: This is not working. To be clear, I am adding items programmatically to the stackpanel.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question, so I assumed it's static XAML.

Comment: Sorry, I should have. Updating the question